# How to submit a form to two different pages depending on the button clicked, without javascript

Tags: php

I have a form with a text area and 2 buttons, i need one of them to submit to the same page its on and the other to submit to another php file. Both buttons need to allow the text areas to be referenced by post. How can i do this.

For Example:

> ```
> <form action="" method="post">
>
>    <textarea></textarea>
>
>    <input type='submit' value='Preview'> //I want this to submit to the same page
>
>    <input type='submit' value='Save'> // I want this to submit to save.php
>
> </form>
> ```

Note: All my html is generated by php through different scripts that change depending on users previous actions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['action1']) || isset($_POST['action2'])) {
    // handle textarea

    if (isset($_POST['action1'])) {
        header('Location: /action1.php');
        exit();
    }

    header('Location: /action2.php');
    exit();
}

?>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="action1" value="Action1">
    <input type="submit" name="action2" value="Action2">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

You only have to be cautious about what happens when the user presses the enter key to submit the form. I.e. what submit will be triggered.

Comment: if i was to use this would the post value of the textarea be maintained when redirected to action2.php?

Comment: @Jai: no it won't. But you can do the handling of the textarea right here. What do you need the textarea value for? Perhaps there is another / better way. Do a redirect is the prefered way after form has been sent succesful.

Comment: the value is being sent to a script save.php to add the content to a database via sql in another script. i suppose i could do that within this script. would it have any implications on security to make database transactions within the same script?

Comment: @Jai: Nopez not at all as long as you sanitize the userinput being inserting it into the database with for example `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, `mysql_real_escape_string()` or even better use PDO's prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I fear this doesn't work in older IEs. They don't send the button's value.

Comment: What version are we talking about?

Comment: I'm not certain, sorry, it's been an issue recently for me though. There is also an issue in that jQuery submit function doesn't send these values may not be relevant though). Edit: IE7 it looks like http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?143073-IE-doesn-t-return-value-of-submit-button&p=736915#post736915

Comment: IE7 with < 1% market share. I don't really care about that one if you don't mind ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Give each submit button a name (e.g button1 and button2).
Submit your form to a single php script. 
On this php script, check the $_POST vars to see which button was clicked.
Then act accordingly, processing your form values and redirecting to whatever page you want afterwards.

To check which button was clicked, do something like:

```
if ($_POST["button1"]) {
  // do stuff
} elseif ($_POST["button2"]) {
  // do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your using `CodeIgniter` there are better ways to do this. (another post for `CodeIgniter` points to this as being duplicate so thought I'd add a better solution for `CI`.)

In my case I have a shopping cart form (for example). On that form I might have buttons : checkout, update cart, and clear.

**Form:**

Here is the form buttons on the cart form screen:

```
<input type="submit" value="Update">
<input type="submit" value="Clear">
<input type="submit" value="Checkout">
```

**Controller:**

The form action points to a `controller` with a method save (`"cart/save/"`). `Save` simply determines which button was clicked and forwards to the appropriate cart function to handle form submission.

**cart/save()**

```
public function save() {
    $submit_button = $this->input->post('submit_button');
    if ($submit_button == 'Update')
        $this->update();
    else if ($submit_button == 'Checkout')
        $this->checkout();
    else if ($submit_button == 'Clear')
        $this->clear();
}
```

Within the controller (`cart`) I simply then have `update()`, `clear()` and `checkout()` functions which the `save()` method calls. There is no need to redirect, via CI's redirect() or php header redirects etc.

I hope that helps someone

Answer (score 1):

you can do it from the server side (as answered before me), you can do it from client side as my answer:(you can even do both):

```
<form action="" id="frm" method="post">
   <textarea></textarea>
   <input type='button' onclick="submitMe(this)" value='Preview'>
   <input type='button' onclick="submitMe(this)" value='Save'> 
</form>

<script>
function submitMe(obj){
  if(obj.value == "Preview"){
   document.getElementById('frm').action = 'preview.html'
  }else{
   document.getElementById('frm').action = 'save.html'
  }
 document.getElementById('frm').submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it on the server side via a redirect.

Comment: But how would the server script differentiate between the two buttons, since they're both of type 'submit'?

Comment: @xtofl: Look at their values.

Comment: ... But the Value is used as display text; how about localization then?

Comment: @xtofl localize the `if` statement on the server side, too?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`formaction`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_formaction.asp) attribute, which can be used on both `<input type="submit">` and `<button type="submit">` buttons.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
   <textarea></textarea>
   <input type='submit' value='Preview'>
   <input type='submit' value='Save' formaction='save.php'>
</form>
```