# Two different submit buttons in CodeIgniter form without Javascript

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have a form where I can add a new category item.

```
<form method="POST" action="backend/categories/form">
    <input type="text" name="title" value="" />

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <button type="submit">Save and add new</button>
</form>
```

What I want to do, is that if i click on `Save` button, it will process a function in controller and redirect me automatically into the previous page (list of categories page), but whenever I click on `Save and add new`, it should process the function but reload the same page without redirecting to the page which is defined in controller's function.

Controller:

```
function form($id){

        // Process the form
        // ...

        // Redirect to the category list page
        redirect($this->config->item('backend_folder').'/categories');
}
```

Any tips to achieve it without using the Javascript ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate! This specifically asks how to do this in CodeIgniter, which has helper functions for you to avoid accessing $_POST directly. The question that this supposedly duplicates does not involve CodeIgniter at all, and does not answer the question asked. This one, however, does, and was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="backend/categories/form">
    <input type="text" name="title" value="" />

    <button type="submit" name="submitForm" value="formSave">SAVE</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submitForm" value="formSaveNew">SAVE AND ADD NEW</button>
</form>
```

Then check the POST data like this:

```
$formSubmit = $this->input->post('submitForm');
if( $formSubmit == 'formSaveNew' )
    redirect($this->config->item('backend_folder').'/categories/form');
else
    redirect($this->config->item('backend_folder').'/categories');
```

Disclaimer: I didn't try that.

Comment: i made a little modifications to your answer and it worked

Comment: @aspirinemaga Great! Do you care posting your changes here? I'll incorporate them into my answer so it may be helpful to other visitors. You can also directly edit my answer, I'll accept the change.

Comment: will this work though to carry across the form data onto the redirect target?

Comment: @wired00 Nope, you'd have to do something along [these lines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12338827/1553481) to do that.

Comment: @likeitlikeit, actually i did it a better way (in my case), using this answer as example, I'd simply put `$this->add()` or `$this->update()` etc according to which button was clicked, it works perfectly. there is no reason to `redirect()`. Even in your answer, I believe a better way to do it is to do something like - `$this->form()` or `$this->index()`. In fact i might make it a proper answer

Comment: @likeitlikeit, I couldn't add an answer here because its locked, but I added a answer to the 'duplicate' here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056963/how-to-submit-a-form-to-two-different-pages-depending-on-the-button-clicked-wit/22597963#22597963

Comment: @wired00 I also don't think this should be a duplicate given this is for CodeIgniter. Your answer over there is more elegant than what I suggested, if it fits your needs. Thanks!

Comment: all good :) Yeah i just had issues with doing re-direct's, for one its a wasted redirect and most importantly in my case, I'd lose the form variables so i'd then have to mess around with storing everything in session or flashdata() etc.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you:

Use this in your save function in your controller. Immediate after Insert/Update code:

```
$task = $_POST['submit'];
//echo $task //Save or SaveNew depending on pressed button

    switch ($task)
    {
        case 'Save':

             $this->session->set_flashdata('message',$this->lang->line('changes_has_been_saved_successfully'));
            $link = redirect('cashdrawer/cashdrawerform/12'); //Link after save button with id
            break;


    case 'SaveNew':

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message',$this->lang->line('this_order_has_been_saved_successfully'));
                $link = redirect('cashdrawer/cashdrawerform'); //Link after save and new
            //echo $link;


    }


     redirect($link);
```

And Change your button as:

```
<button type="submit">Save</button>
    <button type="submit">SaveNew</button>
```

Comment: ok, but how I could make that switch work in form ? I mean let that switch to find out which button where clicked ? by using the `<button name=""...>` ?

Comment: Use switch case in save function of your controller. Just after insert / update record..

Comment: should I do something with `<button`, some values or name to add maybe ?

Comment: Yes.. first `echo($_POST['submit'] );
  die(); ` in save function. You will see the result. It must be either `Save` or `SaveNew`. then assign it to task variable `$task = $_POST['submit']`.

Comment: For what is that `$task` used for ?

Comment: `$task` is used to check if `$task == 'Save'` or `$task == 'Save New'` .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30188/discussion-between-veekay-and-aspirinemaga)